# Execute terminal command without opening terminal

Tags: command-line

In terminal, I have an alias so that when I type `note`, a text document of my notes comes up. Often times when I'm browsing the web I'd like to make a quick note but I don't have terminal open, so I have to Shift-Alt-T to open terminal and then type `note'. And then I have to click off the terminal.

Is there anyway to access terminal commands without opening the terminal so I don't have to do so many key presses? Maybe through a lens or HUD? Alt-`note` would be really nice.. I know I could map terminal to Alt, but then I'd still have to click off it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to transform your alias in an executable and put it in your path.

For example you can put it in `/usr/local/bin`, that should be already in your path.

Then you can launch that program by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> and entering the executable name.

Answer (score 0):

You could youse [guake terminal](http://guake.org/)

What it does is actually run like a console, so when you press a button you defined it will pop up when you are finished just pres ESC and it will be again in the background.